# Sometimes FCM notification not getting and sometime delaying iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for the notification sometimes its working properly and getting it on time but sometimes I am **not getting notification** and **sometimes delaying**. I am stuck from last few week but not getting solution. Anybody can help me please.

1. If my implementation of FCM is wrong from my side then why I am getting some of notification.
2. Same thing happening with firebase when I am testing with firebase console some of notification getting but sometime not getting.
3. I am testing with real device and stable internet connectivity.
4. Already double checked with backend team and android team, working in android properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue..still not getting solution

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB, except when sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024 character limit.
So try to send less data through notification (ask to your backed team if they are sending the notification)

Comment: Thanks for the response.They are sending data only title and actionNumber thats it, so I don't think payload size is mattering but still not getting solution.